# Can I get the workspace popup to come up before I move to another workspace?

Tags: workspaces

Can I set Ubuntu 11.10 to bring up the workspaces by pressing Control-Alt only instead of Control-Alt and an arrow. I would like to see what's in the workspaces **before** moving to a new workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Unity 3d does show a preview the way you've mentioned. If you're using Unity 2d you can have a better preview, and easier switching between workspaces by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Workspace Switching]

Comment: This feature is actually found in both versions of Unity, for what it is worth.